# Rolling 12 months in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have to show sales data for rolling 12 months on a warehouse level. So, I have created 12 cross tabs, 1 for every month and I append the result of each cross tab to one big table. The big table has fields (Part number, month and warehouse names/numbers). The structure of the big table is imported from a base table. My sales data field is of data type 'number' and is named as (hist 1, hist 2 ...... hist 12). The months are in this moment are shown as (1,2,....,12) but I want them to be shown as (Jan,Feb,......,Dec) where hist12 is the data for previous month, hist11 for 2 months previous  and so on and that too rolling. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the OnLoad event of the report.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Report_OnLoad()

Set hist12.Text = Month(DateAdd(Now(), M, -1)) 
Set hist11.Text = Month(DateAdd(Now(), M, -2))
Set hist10.Text = Month(DateAdd(Now(), M, -3))
etc...

End Sub
```

This is obviously "aircode" and would need to be changed to fit your application, but the basic premise (using a combination of Month and DateAdd to calculate the headings of the months in your report) is sound.